# Java Network Connection - No Further Information Error

Tags: java, networking, router

Alright, I have a java server setup using port 6567 and IP address 0.0.0.0 as to accept any connection. When I attempt to connect over my local network (192.168.1.15) I am able to connect just fine using the server. However when I switch to a non-local IP address (my routers public IP) I am unable to connect to it.

I have the router port forwarded and the proper rules in place on my firewall/etc. Is there any limitations on Java connecting in this fashion? I'm able to connect externally but not internally. Any thoughts on what might be causing this problem?

I'm starting to think it might be a router-specific problem, being that it could be rejecting the connection but I am unable to test that currently.

Comment: You don't have the port forwarding or firewall rules set up correctly.

Comment: I entirelly disabled the firewall for my testing - there is no firewall. I don't see how I could have messed up the port forwarding, as it works just fine with external connections. Not to mention that if I was able to make a connection at all, I severely doubt its an issue with them. As my post says I am wondering about either Java specific issues or router specific issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just the router itself that rejects internal connections using an external IP address. My personal fix was to just add a bit of testing code that automatically changes the IP if on a local machine to 127.0.0.1 rather then the external IP.

Worked flawlessly both on my own PC and having people connect externally once I set that up.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm I'm not sure about it but maybe that will help.

Most probable, Your ServerSocket gets bound to a local IP address (e.g. 0.0.0.0) and `ServerSocket` binds to the port address there; and wouldn't respond to any requests coming from an IP address. Try `new ServerSocket(4444, 50, InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { YOU IP ADDRESS }).`

or check again firewall

edit: Tell me how did you tried to connect from other IP than local?

Comment: Not sure if it matters - It does work with external connections as far as I can tell. When I tested the port forwarding it got to the server successfully. The only thing I am concerned about is that I want it to accept connections from any IP address (which is what I thought 0.0.0.0 did, is that correct?).

Comment: What you say about binding to 0.0.0.0 isn't correct, and your solution would throw a `BindException.`